# Different results for string iteration in Go

Tags: go

Just used two simple ways to iterate a string in Go. The first one seems right but the second way got minus numbers starting with -97. Could somebody knows why?

```
func main() {
    str := "abc"

    for i := 0; i < len(str) ; i++ {
        println(str[i] - 'a')
    }

    for x := range str {
        println(x - 'a')
    }
}
```

The result is -

```
0
1
2
-97
-96
-95
```

Comment: `range` returns the index first: https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for x := range str {
    println(x - 'a')
}
```

x contains the index of the letter

what you want to do is take the second value returned by the range and ignore the first

```
for _, x := range str {
    println(x - 'a')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!